# problem while using border shorthand property

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following border shorthand property (border: 10px 2px 3px 4px solid black;) why does it not work.

I tried (border: 10px 2px 3px 4px solid black;) using border shorthand property, and in browser it is not showing up any border to my element

Comment: you can specify only **one** width, read the doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MDN docs: !(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border), the shorthand property you trying to apply should be like so: `border: 1px solid black;` since you are trying to use border as padding|margin shorthand property it will not work.

border shorthand property consists off:

```
border: <border-width> <border-style> <border-color>
```

instead you can try this:

```
border: solid black;
border-width: 10px 2px 3px 4px;
```